# Can't fetch data in RecyclerView from JSON after filtering

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

I have one Activity in my application where user searches for particular item from list, but he can also sort those items in list by cities. And that i'm doing with spinner. After he clicks on spinner to sort items, he is fetching data again from server.

The problem occurs when he searches before ordering items in list by cities. Filtering is working fine, but after we are filtering items in list, i can't use anymore spinner and fetch ordered data by selected city. The list is showing previous records ordered at the beginning with default value from spinner. Can't fetch data anymore. I don't know why.

This is the code from that Activity:

```
public class SearchGroupsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    Toolbar mToolbar;
    SessionManager mSessionManager;
    List<Group> mGroups;
    RecyclerView mList;
    RecyclerGroupsAdapter mAdapter;
    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    MyProgressDialog mDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_groups);
        mSessionManager = new SessionManager(this);
        mSharedPreferences = new SharedPreferences(this);
        mGroups = new ArrayList<>();

        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        setAdapter();
        setToolbar();

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.group_cities, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        if (!mSessionManager.isLoggedIn()) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
            this.finish();
        }

    }

    private void setAdapter() {
        mList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        mAdapter = new RecyclerGroupsAdapter(this, mGroups);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        mList.setLayoutManager(manager);
        mList.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    private void loadGroups(String selectedCity) {
        mDialog = new MyProgressDialog(this, 1);
        mDialog.show();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                AppConfig.ORDER_GROUPS_BY_CITY + "/" + selectedCity,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                hidePDialog();

                if (mGroups.size() > 0) {
                    mGroups.clear();
                }

                try {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = object.getBoolean("error");
                    JSONArray groups = object.getJSONArray("groups");
                    if (!error) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < groups.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject groupObject = groups.getJSONObject(i);
                            Group group = new Group();
                            group.setGroupName(groupObject.optString("group_name"));
                            mGroups.add(group);
                        }
                    }

                    // notify adapter that data has changed
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                hidePDialog();
                Toast.makeText(SearchGroupsActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }

    private String orderGroupsByCity() {
        String cityName = "";
        int selectedFilterOption = mSharedPreferences.getCityFilter();

        switch (selectedFilterOption) {
            case 0:
                cityName = "Nis";
                break;
            case 1:
                cityName = "Beograd";
                break;
            case 2:
                cityName = "Paracin";
                break;
        }

        return cityName;
    }

    private void setToolbar() {
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (mToolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        }
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("NADJI EKIPU");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                this.finish();
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        int selectedCityFilter = GroupsCity.NIS;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                // NIS
                selectedCityFilter = GroupsCity.NIS;
                break;
            case 1:
                // BEOGRAD
                selectedCityFilter = GroupsCity.BEOGRAD;
                break;
            case 2:
                // PARACIN
                selectedCityFilter = GroupsCity.PARACIN;
                break;
        }
        mSharedPreferences.setCityFilter(selectedCityFilter);
        String selectedCity = orderGroupsByCity();
        loadGroups(selectedCity); // HERE WE ARE FETCHING DATA ORDERED BY SELECTED CITY
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (mDialog != null) {
            mDialog.dismiss();
            mDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        final List<Group> filteredModelList = filter(mGroups, newText);
        mAdapter.setFilter(filteredModelList);

        return true;
    }

    private List<Group> filter(List<Group> groups, String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();

        final List<Group> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Group group : groups) {
            final String text = group.getGroupName().toLowerCase();
            if (text.contains(query)) {
                filteredModelList.add(group);
            }
        }
        return filteredModelList;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to find specific problem in your application, then shows us your problem instead of giving the code and helping you find the problem

Comment: I know where is the problem, but i do not know how to solve it. In override method onQueryTextChange i'm setting to adapter new filteredList with searched items. After i try to load data from server in method loadGroups with new passed parameters, i'm getting the same filtered list.

Comment: If you search and then click the Spinner you first filter the adapter(which will work ok) and then you do that request. However, when the request returns with the data, you simply add it to the groups list on which your adapter isn't based(my assumption), so calling notifyDatasetChanged() will be useless. So in your loadGroups() method you need to do again the filtering by calling the filter() method and setting on the adapter the resulting list(like you currently do in the listener for the SearchView).

Comment: That it's it. Can you post the answer, so i can assign you this 50 points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you first search and then click the Spinner you will filter the adapter(which will work ok) and then you'll do that request(when the user selects a city) to the server.

However, when the request returns with the data, you currently just add it to the `groups` list on which your adapter isn't based(my assumption, as you pass a new list when you do the filtering). So in this case simply calling `notifyDatasetChanged()` will be useless as the adapter will not see the new data items.

In order to solve this problem, in your loadGroups() method you need to do again the filtering by calling the `filter()` method and setting on the adapter the resulting list(like you currently do in the listener for the SearchView).